# When can I apply for an Austrian Visa-C after I apply for a Visa-D?

Tags: working-visas, austria

After how long can I apply for a C-visa after I have applied for a D-visa? Do I have to wait a certain amount of time (e.g. 180 days)? Will I be violating any rules if I stay more than 180 days based on a D-visa and a C-visa combined? Or do I have to ensure that my total stay within one year is less than 180 days?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you spend in a country for which you have a valid D visa does not count for the purposes of the 90/180 rule.  You should therefore be able to apply immediately.  However, your application is likely to receive greater scrutiny, so you shouldn't plan to return to Austria unless you have a very clear reason to motivate your trip and a clear and compelling reason to return to your country of residence after the end of your trip.